# How to save logs to file filterwise?

Tags: android, android-logcat

Is it possible to get only the app specific logs not all the logs that the device is producing using some filters or so?

i have tried this,

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/KeysersData/LogData.log");`

i want to save specific tag related data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution and that is

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/KeysersData/LogData.log"+" -s *:E");`